# Xml reader cross-platform c#

Tags: c#, xml, cross-platform

I have a project based in MasterDetailPageNAvigation xamarin.forms cross-plataform, I need read from a xml file to my project to present the information in several layouts. i can't read the file to use in layouts.

xml structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<conferencia>
    <info>
        <loc_img></loc_img>
        <infor></infor>
    </info>
    <KeynoteSpeaker>
        <Keynote id="Keynote 1">
            <foto></foto>
            <nome></nome>
            <organizacao></organizacao>
            <funcao></funcao>
            <abstract></abstract>
            <Bio></Bio>
        </Keynote>
    </KeynoteSpeaker>
    <Program>
        <Day id="">
            <block>
                <nome></nome>
                <sala></sala>
                <hora_inicio></hora_inicio>
                <hora_fim></hora_fim>
                <descricao1>
                    <desc></desc>
                    <orador></orador>
                </descricao1>
            </block>
        </Paper>        
    </AcceptedPapers>
    <Contacts>
        <Email></Email>
        <PagWeb></PagWeb>
        <Facebook></Facebook>
    </Contacts>
    <Venue>
        <Latitude></Latitude>
        <Longitude></Longitude>
        <Label></Label>
        <Adress></Adress>
    </Venue>
</conferencia>
```

Keynote and Day have severals blocks.

I have this functions to get the context of file:

```
public class Conferencia
    {



        public Info Info { get; set; } = new Info();
        public List<KeynoteSpeaker> KeynoteSpeakers { get; set; } = new List<KeynoteSpeaker>();
        public List<Committee> Committees { get; set; } = new List<Committee>();
        public List<Programme> Programmes { get; set; } = new List<Programme>();
        public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; } = new List<Contact>();
        public Venue Venue { get; set; } = new Venue();

    }

    public class Info
    {
        public string localizaçao_imagem { get; set; }
        public string info { get; set; }
    }
    public class KeynoteSpeaker
    {        
        public string id { get; set; }
        public List<Keynote> Keynotes { get; set; } = new List<Keynote>();
    } 

    public class Keynote
    {
        public string foto { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public string organizacao { get; set; }
        public string funcao { get; set; }
        public string abs { get; set; }
        public string Bio { get; set; }
    }

    public class Committee
    {
        public string Tipo { get; set; }
        public List<Elemento> Elementos { get; set; } = new List<Elemento>();

    }

    public class Elemento
    {
        public string elemento { get; set; }
    }

    public class Programme
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public List<Day> Days { get; set; } = new List<Day>();
    }

    public class Day
    {
        public string Nome_Sessao { get; set; }
        public string Sala { get; set; }
        public DateTime Hora_Inicio { get; set; }
        public DateTime Hora_Fim { get; set; }
    }

    public class AcceptedPaper
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public List<Paper> Papers { get; set; } = new List<Paper>();
    }

    public class Paper
    {
        public string desc { get; set; }
        public string sala { get; set; }
        public string day { get; set; }
        public string hour { get; set; }
        public List<block> blocks { get; set; } = new List<block>();
    }

    public class block
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string orador { get; set; }
    } 

    public class Contact
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Pagina_Web { get; set; }
        public string Facebook { get; set; }
    }


    public class Venue
    {
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public string Adress { get; set; }
    }
```

How i can do it?

thanks...

Answer (score -1):

Use xml linq like below.  The are som error with the xml you  posted.  I assume you actual xml doesn't contain these errors.  I flatten the results out so you views should work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            Conferencia conferencia = doc.Descendants().Select(x => new Conferencia()
            {
                Info = x.Elements("info").Select(y => new Info()
                {
                    localizaçao_imagem = (string)y.Element("loc_img"),
                    info = (string)y.Element("infor")
                }).FirstOrDefault(),
                KeynoteSpeakers = new List<Keynote>(
                    x.Descendants("Keynote").Select(y => new Keynote() {
                        id = (string)y.Attribute("id"),
                        foto = (string)y.Element("foto"),
                        nome = (string)y.Element("nome"),
                        organizacao = (string)y.Element("organizacao"),
                        funcao = (string)y.Element("funcao"),
                        abs = (string)y.Element("abstract"),
                        Bio = (string)y.Element("Bio")
                    })
                ).ToList(),
                Programmes = new Programme()
                {
                    Days = x.Descendants("Day").Select(y => new Day()
                    {
                        id = (string)y.Attribute("id"),
                        Blocks = y.Elements("block").Select(z => new Block() {

                               Nome_Sessao = (string)y.Descendants("nome").FirstOrDefault(),
                               Sala = (string)y.Descendants("sala").FirstOrDefault(),
                               Hora_Inicio  =  (string)y.Descendants("hora_inicio").FirstOrDefault() == "" ? new DateTime() : (DateTime)y.Descendants("hora_inicio").FirstOrDefault(),
                               Hora_Fim = (string)y.Descendants("hora_inicio").FirstOrDefault() == "" ? new DateTime() : (DateTime)y.Descendants("hora_fim").FirstOrDefault(),
                         }).ToList(),

                    }).ToList()
                },
                Contacts = x.Elements("Contacts").Select(y => new Contact() {
                        Email = (string)y.Attribute("Email"),
                        Pagina_Web = (string)y.Descendants("PagWeb").FirstOrDefault(),
                        Facebook = (string)y.Descendants("Facebook").FirstOrDefault()
                }).ToList(),
                Venue = x.Elements("Venue").Select(y => new Venue() {
                        Latitude =  (string)y.Element("Latitude") == "" ? 0 : (double?)y.Element("Latitude"),
                        Longitude = (string)y.Element("Longitude") == "" ? 0 : (double?)y.Element("Longitude"),
                        Label = (string)y.Descendants("Label").FirstOrDefault(),
                        Adress = (string)y.Descendants("Address").FirstOrDefault()
                }).FirstOrDefault()
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
    public class Conferencia
    {



        public Info Info { get; set; }
        public List<Keynote> KeynoteSpeakers { get; set; }
        public List<Committee> Committees { get; set; }
        public Programme Programmes { get; set; }
        public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
        public Venue Venue { get; set; }

    }

    public class Info
    {
        public string localizaçao_imagem { get; set; }
        public string info { get; set; }
    }

    public class Keynote
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string foto { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public string organizacao { get; set; }
        public string funcao { get; set; }
        public string abs { get; set; }
        public string Bio { get; set; }
    }

    public class Committee
    {
        public string Tipo { get; set; }
        public List<Elemento> Elementos { get; set; }

    }

    public class Elemento
    {
        public string elemento { get; set; }
    }

    public class Programme
    {
        public List<Day> Days { get; set; }
    }
    public class Day
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public List<Block> Blocks { get; set; }
    }

    public class Block
    {
        public string Nome_Sessao { get; set; }
        public string Sala { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Hora_Inicio { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Hora_Fim { get; set; }
    }

    public class AcceptedPaper
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public List<Paper> Papers { get; set; }
    }

    public class Paper
    {
        public string desc { get; set; }
        public string sala { get; set; }
        public string day { get; set; }
        public string hour { get; set; }
        public List<block> blocks { get; set; }
    }

    public class block
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string orador { get; set; }
    } 

    public class Contact
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Pagina_Web { get; set; }
        public string Facebook { get; set; }
    }


    public class Venue
    {
        public double? Latitude { get; set; }
        public double? Longitude { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public string Adress { get; set; }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I updated code to include the classes you added.  The xml and classes are not consistent so I did the best I could to get them to match.  I modified the classes slightly.

Comment: thanks by the support, but what you think when you say the xml and classes are not consistent.

Comment: There should be an id for each KeyNote.  The class Day should have an id for each day not just one id.   A Day should have more than one Block.  Why do you need an Array of KeyNoteSpeaker when you have an array of KeyNote?  Why does Block and Paper both have DataTime.  A Day should be broken into blocks that contain papers.  I move some properties in my classes that are different from your definitions.

Comment: A day have between 4 to 10 blocks so i need array, keynoteSpeaker have 6 keynotes. Block and Paper have both DataTime because in block the format was like <hora_inicio>10:00</hora_inico> and in paper was <hour> 10H00m> and i don't need hora_fim.

Comment: There was nothing wrong with day and block.  I was having issues with papers. Why does both keynoteSpeaker and keynote both have arrays?  The xml posted was missing the open tag for paper so I didn't know what tags were in the paper.  I think paper belongs inside the block tag.

Comment: i make a correction in Xml file and functions, but appear a error "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.".
I have the file xml embeded resource and the path is "nameproject.namefile.xml"

Comment: I try show in the xaml.cs like:


Conferencia loader = new Conferencia();
layout.Children.Add(new Label() { Text = loader.Info.info });

Comment: Check if xml has errors.  From VS menu : Project : add new item : xml file.  Paste xml into view.  Error will show in Error List just like compiler errors.

Comment: thanks by the help. one more thing, 

i have
 <pre>public class Committee
    {
        public List<tipo> Tipos { get; set; } 
    }

    public class tipo
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public List<elemento> Elementos { get; set; }
    }
    public class elemento
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
       
    }<code>

and i want use the list elemento in xaml.cs, but dont'a appear elemento, just tipo, how i can access to the list elemento.